# Как объединить несколько условий в одно в питоне?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, if

Работаю с API Vk и хочу упросить код. Так как таких условий у меня может быть 10ки, а заполнять этим весь код не хочется. Есть ли способ сокращения?

Вот код:

```
def safe_file(posts):
    with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        title = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        title. writerow(['text', 'image', 'url'])
        for post in posts:
            try:
                if post ['id']:
                    i = post ['id']
                else:
                    i = 'pass'
                if post ['text']:
                    text = post ['text']
                else:
                    text = 'pass'
                if post ['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']:
                    img = post ['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']
                else:
                    img = 'pass'
            except:
                pass
                img = 'pass'

            title.writerow((text, i, img))
```

Мне нужно упростить эту часть кода:

```
for post in posts:
            try:
                if post ['id']:
                    i = post ['id']
                else:
                    i = 'pass'
                if post ['text']:
                    text = post ['text']
                else:
                    text = 'pass'
                if post ['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']:
                    img = post ['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']
                else:
                    img = 'pass'
            except:
                pass
                img = 'pass'
```

Comment: `i = post['id'] or 'pass'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, можно условный **оператор**

```
if post ['id']:
    i = post ['id']
else:
    i = 'pass'
```

Записать короче с помощью условного **выыражения**:

```
i = post['id'] if post['id'] else 'pass'
```

После этого я бы сделал функцию, выполняющую все три присваивания:

```
def con_ass(post):
    i = post['id'] if post['id'] else 'pass'
    text = ...
    img = ...
    reurn i,text,img
```

А в программе бы тогда эти присвоения выглядели бы как-то так:

```
i,text,img = con_ass(post)
```

Мне кажется - достаточно компактно и обозримо.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы предложил вариант с дефолтом так назовем это

```
def try_extract_image_url(post):
    try:
        return post['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']
    except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
        return None

for post in posts:
    id = post['id'] or 'pass'
    text = post['text'] or 'pass'
    img = try_extract_image_url(post) or 'pass'
```

Можно еще над этим поработать и придумать что то получше например заменить 'pass' на что то более специфичное что бы дальше по коду это было проще фильтровать и обрабатывать. Например завести [специальный объект](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html) для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Исправленный код:

```
for post in posts:
            try:
                if post ['id']:
                    i = post ['id']
                elif: post ['text']:
                    text = post ['text']
                elif: post ['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']:
                    img = post ['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']
                else:
                    img = 'pass'
            except:
                pass
                img = 'pass'
```

Comment: а чей код вы исправили ?

Comment: в данном примере получился код который не эквивалентен предыдущему указанному в вопросе. то есть он будет работать не корректно. да и еще одно маленькое замечание по поводу блоков try except. нужно их использовать с минимальным скоупом и указанием конкретных исключений которые могут быть впринципе обработаны или проигнорированы. иначе может получиться так что код будете проглатывать исключения которые могли бы говорить об ошибке в нем.

Comment: в вопросе......